# Autoclose a tkinter.messagebox.showinfo

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a simple tkinter.messagebox.showinfo inside a python code, how can I close the messagebox inside the python code as the code runs?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as far as I know because the tkinter.messagebox.showinfo waits for user input, which is to click the button. This is what showinfo is supposed to do.

If you want to display something to the user and make it disappear after a while (say a loading... sign) I would suggest using a progrssbar instead of a messagebox.

In any case, you will need another thread to control the functionality of your current thread.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323574/how-to-connect-a-progress-bar-to-a-function) may give you more info about using threads this way.

Also note that it's recommended that secondary threads are not given access to tkinter objects.