# GUI programming using Tkinter Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a Tkinter GUI having 2 entry fields, 2 buttons ( initialization of these not shown in code). There is one more button (initialized in code) which performs the main task of performing change detection on two images. Also there is a progress bar.

Now, when the task of change detection has been completed, I want to display the 4 images(pre, post, aligned, chng) returned by `wave.changedetection()` in a separate Tkinter window. I want the new window to come only after `changedetection()` has completed.(`wave.py` is my own file, not some module)

Unfortunately, if I try to add code to make new window, `Tk.Toplevel()` ,after the `wave.changedetection()` call, nothing happens and the main GUI window becomes unresponsive and has to be killed.

There is no way to know when the new created thread (`start_thread`)completes it's work, so that I can do `Tk.Toplevel()` there.

How can I do what I require?

```
class GUI(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent)
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent  = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.button = Tkinter.Button(text = "Start")
        self.button.bind('<Button-1>', self.OnButtonClick)
        self.button.pack()
        self.int = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.pgbar = Tkinter.ProgressBar(variable = self.int, mode = determinate)

    def OnButtonClick(self,event):
        #this func has been made since I have more buttons.It may seem redundant here
        self.button['command'] = self.start_thread()
        self.update_idletasks()

     def start_thread(self):
        self.int_var.set(1)
        q = queue.Queue()
        self.secondary_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.change)
        self.secondary_thread.start()
        self.after(50, self.check_queue, q)

     def check_queue(self, q):
         while True:            
            try: 
                x = wave.q.get_nowait()
            except queue.Empty :
                self.after(50,self.check_queue,q)
                break
            else:
                self.int_var.set(x)                
                if x == 6:
                    self.button3['state'] = 'normal'
                    break

    def change(self):
    '''The 6 functions of wave.changedetection() change the value of self.int 
       due to which progress bar progresses.'''
          pre, post, aligned, chng = wave.changedetection(self.entry_1.get(),
                                                    self.entry_2.get())
if __name__ == '__main__':
     gui = GUI(None)
     gui.mainloop()
```

code to update progress bar taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323574/how-to-connect-a-progress-bar-to-a-function?lq=1) (2nd answer,Honest Abe's answer)

Comment: Nowhere in your code are you creating an instance of `Toplevel`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be able to differentiate name spaces, i.e. this is in the main window and this is in the Toplevel.  I would suggest that you get the Toplevels working first and then decide if you want to add threading or not.  The code below is a simple example of creating Toplevels and shows how to place widgets in a specific name space (window in this case).  You may or may not want a separate "create a Toplevel" class if there are functions you want to associate with each Toplevel's namespace. Also there are examples on the web on using Tkinter's "after" to update a progressbar.  That is a different question so start another thread if you have questions about the progressbar.

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

from functools import partial

class OpenToplevels():
    """ open and close additional Toplevels with a button
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.button_ctr=0

        ## in the "root" namespace *********************
        but=tk.Button(self.root, text="Open a Toplevel",
                      command=self.open_another)
        but.grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Button(self.root, text="Exit Tkinter", bg="red",
                  command=self.root.quit).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="we")
        self.root.mainloop()

    def close_it(self, id):
        ## destroy the window in this id's namespace ***********
        id.destroy()
##        id.withdraw()
##          id.iconify()

    def open_another(self):
        self.button_ctr += 1
        id = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        id.title("Toplevel #%d" % (self.button_ctr))

        ## in the "id for this Toplevel" namespace ***********
        tk.Button(id, text="Close Toplevel #%d" % (self.button_ctr),
                  command=partial(self.close_it, id),
                  bg="orange", width=20).grid(row=1, column=0)

Ot=OpenToplevels()
```